# Certificate store

Tags: windows, certificate, store

I know that Windows certificate Store exist in registry at SystemCertificates key (\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates).
 But I want to know that Are there some files associated with these stores? and where's the location of them?
and secondly, where is the private keys, in registry or in files?

Thank you

Comment: The private keys are not on your computer.  There is an excellent chance that any given private key for a certificate included in Windows' default certificate store is in an HSM in a vault somewhere, with men with guns standing outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private keys are generally on the file system, but they are encrypted by the OS.  Usually located in c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto (or equivalent on older OSes).

Comment: Is there any solution for decrypte them and obtain private keys?

Comment: That would kind of defeat the purpose, wouldn't it?  I believe the details are private but I would guess it includes using the DPAPI.  If the keys are exportable, you can export them from the Certificate Manager.

Comment: At some point, the private key is needed on the machine in non-encrypted form. After all, it is there for a reason. 
So, theoretically, there must be a way to get hold of the non-encrypted key, even if it is not marked as 'exportable'. Perhaps using a debugger..?